# Flic Bluetooth Button and Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have written my mobile app in Xamarin.Forms and it works great in iOS and Android.  My users are wanting to me to integrate a Flic button into the program.  Flic is a bluetooth button that allows integration into your app.  Click once and something in your app can happen.  Click twice ... click and hold ... etc.

The sdk for Flic is quite good but they limit examples and information to just "raw" Android or iOS.  Can anyone suggest how to integrate the sdk/dll files into xamarin.forms?  I don't know much about bindings, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to integrate the sdk/dll files into xamarin.forms?

Fortunately, someone has already done it.You can add the binding library of iOS and Android from Nuget.

[image]

You can implement the method in iOS and Android .Then use the `dependency service` to call the method in forms.

If you want to learn more about how to bind native library or package in iOS and Android.
You can refer to [iOS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/native-references?context=xamarin/ios) and [Android Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/).

Comment: I feel dumb - I looked everywhere except inside Visual Studio!  Thank you.